# python subprocess does not produce output when running in daemon mode on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04, python-daemon

I have a Python script, which runs as a daemon, which uses subprocess to get output from /usr/bin/host. This script runs fine in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 but starting 22.04 the subprocess dies with SIGABRT.
Example code to reproduce the issue:

```
import subprocess
import daemon
from lockfile.pidlockfile import PIDLockFile

def log(msg):
    with open("/tmp/outfile","a") as outfile:
        outfile.write(msg+'\n')

def test(msg):
    log(msg)
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/host', '-t', 'srv', '_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com'], encoding="utf-8")
    except Exception as e:
        log(str(e))
        return
    log(output)
    return

test("single run")
with daemon.DaemonContext(pidfile=PIDLockFile("/tmp/test.pid")):
    test("run as daemon")
log("All done")
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 the output looks like:

```
single run
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 636 ad02.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 389 ad02.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 389 ad01.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 636 ad01.local.hospital.com.

run as daemon
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 636 ad02.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 389 ad02.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 389 ad01.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 636 ad01.local.hospital.com.

All done
```

On Ubuntu 22.04 I get:

```
single run
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 636 ad02.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 389 ad01.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 389 ad02.local.hospital.com.
_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com has SRV record 0 100 636 ad01.local.hospital.com.

run as daemon
Command '['/usr/bin/host', '-t', 'srv', '_ldap._tcp.local.hospital.com']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
All done
```

I tried multiple PC's running 22.04 and got the same result everywhere.  Why would the subprocess.check_output give different results running as daemon or not?

Note: I also tried subprocess.Popen and subprocess.run but that does not make any difference.